# how to fetch an item from an observable collection by index

Tags: c#

Why does this not work?  It throws an index out of range exception.  The item doesn't have on object in the third index, but I'm trying to check for that.  How else do I check for an empty index?

```
if (MyBusinessObject.MyObservableCollection[2] != null)
{
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: The third index doesn’t contain a NULL. It doesn’t exist. You need to check a Length property on the collection. Or size or some such on some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception "index is out of range" is saying that your use of the 'indexer' ("[2]") is referring to something which is outside the limits of the collection. In other words there isn't a third item in the list (the indexer is zero-based).

```
//    I think what you're trying to do is...
if (MyBusinessObject.MyObservableCollection.Count >= 3)
{
    doSomething();
}
```